# Export and Import Synapse Triggers

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I'm setting up secondary region for my synapse workspace, is there a way I can export all the triggers from one workspace to another?

Comment: Could you please provide your approach?

Comment: You are exporting from where to where could you please give the clarification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 3 options, as far as I can see:

1. set up Git and Devops integration between your 2 workspaces and then set up a release pipeline to copy everything from one workspace to the other. Here is a link to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/cicd/continuous-integration-delivery). This is the best way if you have a lot to copy, and\or want to create a way to copy between environments on a regular basis.
2. Build a PowerShell script to get information about triggers from one workspace and then create them in the second workspace. Try the commands [Get-AzSynapseTrigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.synapse/get-azsynapsetrigger?view=azps-9.4.0) to copy from one workspace and [Set-AzSynapseTrigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.synapse/set-azsynapsetrigger?view=azps-9.4.0) to create on the new environment.
3. If you have few triggers, simply copying them is the simplest, thought programmatically disappointing solution.